# How to correctly make the interaction of a property with the logic of a method?

Tags: javascript

As in the method of the base class "kick" to define the logic of evasion from the attack, at the same time to output to the console a message about whether or not the harm was done, or the target evaded ?

```js
function Unit(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion, type) {
    this._maxHealth = maxHealth;
    this._currentHeaalth = maxHealth;
    this._basicDamage = basicDamage;
    this._evasion = evasion;
    this._type = type;
/*method for showing the status of life, true if the "health" is greater than 0 and false if equal to or lower */    
    this._isAlive = function () {
        return this._currentHeaalth > 0
    };
 /* a method that shows the level of health*/
    this._getFormattedHealth = function () {
        return this._currentHeaalth + '/' + 
        this._maxHealth + ' HP';
    };
/*a method that returns the base damage of the heroand damage to the weapon (if it is set)*/    
    this._getDamage = function () {
        return (this.weapon ? this.weapon._getDamage() : 0) + this._basicDamage;
    };
/* The method of hitting the hero for the chosen purpose*/    
    this._kick = function (target) {
        if (this._isAlive()) {
            target._currentHeaalth = Math.max(0, target._currentHeaalth - this._getDamage());
        }
        return this;
    };
/*method for showing all the characteristics of the hero and changes with them*/
    this.toString = function () {
        return "Type-" + this._type + ", is alive - " + this._isAlive() + this._getFormattedHealth() + ", hero current damage-" + this._getDamage() + "points" + ", hero evasion - " + this._evasion;
    }
}
function Archer(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this._type = "archer";

}
var archer = new Archer(60, 5, 0.6);
function Swordsman(maxHealth, basicDamage, evasion) {
    Unit.apply(this, arguments);
    this._type = "swordsman";
}
var swordsman = new Swordsman(100, 10, 0.3);
// cycle until someone dies
while (archer._isAlive() && swordsman._isAlive()) {
    archer._kick(swordsman);
    swordsman._kick(archer);
}
console.log(archer.toString());
console.log(swordsman.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. What is your problem? What part of your code does not work as expected?

Comment: As in the method "kick" to determine the logic of evasion from the attack, at the expense of the property "evasion" at the same time to output to the console a message about whether or was harmed, or the target evaded.

Comment: Repeating what you already wrote won't help me understand it.